# Certificate and provisioning profile required for testing

Tags: testing, cordova, certificate, provisioning-profile, steroids

Are you required to have a certificate and provisioning profile to start building and testing with PhoneGap? If not, is there another way to test your application?

I would prefer to save myself the $99 for now and just get a developer account once my application is finished.

Answer (score 1):

No need for certificate and provisioning profile when developing with steroids. Download AppGyver scanner app from itunes:
https://itunes.apple.com/se/app/appgyver-scanner/id575076515?mt=8

Open terminal and go to your steroid project dir, type: "steroids connect --serve".
Your web browser will open and show a QR-code. Scan the QR-code with AppGyver scanner app and your steroid application will run on the device. Fast and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is another way. You can use the simulators to test your application. And if you would want to test on a device then you could look more into [Steroids](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids) and the Appgyver Scanner to help you out.